# Xcode: error Class XYZ does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol

Tags: iphone, xcode

I get this error message regarding the line "[parser setDelegate:self];" below:

Class 'ProcessiController' does not implement the 'NSXMLParserDelegate' protocol...

This is the code:

```
<!-- language: C-objective -->

@implementation ProcessiController


-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"processi" ofType:@"xml"];
    stories = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataFilePath]];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    NSLog(@"file trovato e caricato");

}
```

And this is the .h file:

```
<!-- language: C-objective -->

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomCellProcessiController.h"
#import "GenericaProcessiController.h"


@interface ProcessiController : UITableViewController {


    NSXMLParser *parser; //utilizzato per il parsing
    NSMutableArray *stories; 
    NSMutableDictionary *item;

    NSString *currentElement;
    NSMutableString *currentName;
    NSMutableString *fileName;

    UIView *myHeader;

}
```

Thanks for any contribution! However, it will be helpful only if explained step by step what to modify since I have no programming knowledge (but am brave enough to tinker with the code :-) )

Answer (score 2):

By using following line,

```
[parser setDelegate:self];
```

you indicate that the current class conforms to the [`NSXMLParserDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

What you need to do to make it work is to have your current class implement the required delegate methods.

Here are some links that explain how `Protocols` work in iOS:

[iOS protocols and delegates. Basic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595140/ios-protocols-and-delegates-basic-questions)

http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: Very nice of you for answering, Shaharyar, I will look into it asap, cheers!

Comment: Hi, I followed the links but I REALLY WOULD BE GREATFUL for plain explanation what changes in my code I should apply to get rid of the error, thank you for your comprehension.

Comment: Have a quick look at this page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i